# Pivot a table with multiple values

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I'm trying to pivot an access table with multiple result values like the first table in the image below. Anyone has an idea on how to get a result like in the second table?

[image: Pivot table sample]

Answer (score -1):

You can´t use multiple agregations with Pivot table, but there is an easy solution for your problem

By creating two pivot tables and joining both tables separed by Price and Weight is posible.

```
/*PRICE*/

SELECT  MONTH
       ,ITEM
       ,STORE
       ,MANAGER
       ,[TY] AS TY_PRICE
       ,[LY] AS LY_PRICE
       ,[PY] AS PY_PRICE
INTO ##TMP_PRICE
FROM(
      select MONTH
            ,ITEM
            ,STORE
            ,MANAGER
            ,TYPE
            ,SUM(PRICE) AS PRICE
      FROM TABLE_X
      GROUP BY MONTH
            ,ITEM
            ,STORE
            ,MANAGER
            ,TYPE) AS TMP
PIVOT(
MAX(PRICE)
FOR TYPE IN([TY],[LY],[PY])
) AS PVT

/*WEIGHT*/

SELECT  MONTH
       ,ITEM
       ,STORE
       ,MANAGER
       ,[TY] AS TY_WEIGHT
       ,[LY] AS LY_WEIGHT
       ,[PY] AS PY_WEIGHT
INTO ##TMP_WEIGHT
FROM(
      select MONTH
            ,ITEM
            ,STORE
            ,MANAGER
            ,TYPE
            ,SUM(WEIGHT) AS WEIGHT
      FROM TABLE_X
      GROUP BY MONTH
            ,ITEM
            ,STORE
            ,MANAGER
            ,TYPE) AS TMP
PIVOT(
MAX(WEIGHT)
FOR TYPE IN([TY],[LY],[PY])
) AS PVT
```

After both tables are created join them

```
SELECT ISNULL(TP.month,TW.month)  as MONTH
      ,ISNULL(TP.ITEM,TW.ITEM) AS ITEM
      ,ISNULL(TP.STORE,TW.STORE) AS STORE
      ,ISNULL(TP.MANAGER,TW.MANAGER) AS MANAGER
      ,TY_WEIGHT
      ,LY_WEIGHT
      ,PY_WEIGHT
      ,TY_PRICE
      ,LY_PRICE
      ,PY_PRICE
FROM ##TMP_PRICE TP
FULL JOIN ##TMP_WEIGHT TW ON (TP.MONTH = TW.MONTH AND TP.ITEM = TW.ITEM 
                            AND TP.STORE = TW.ITEM AND TP.MANAGER = TW.MANAGER)
```

Comment: This looks like Transact SQL, right? So it wouldn't work in Microsoft Access.

Answer (score -1):

Because you can't use pivot queries as sub queries in a query in Microsoft Access, you would have to save two pivot queries to separate Microsoft Access query objects:

> > Pivot_Price

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Price]) AS SumPrice
SELECT [month], item, store, manager
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [month], item, store, manager
PIVOT [type];
```

> > Pivot_Weight

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Weight]) AS SumWeight
SELECT [month], item, store, manager
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [month], item, store, manager
PIVOT [type];
```

And then join them in a third query:

```
SELECT
  PP.Month,
  PP.item,
  PP.store,
  PP.manager,
  PP.TY AS [TY-Price],
  PP.LY AS [LY-Price],
  PP.PY AS [PY-Price],
  PW.TY AS [TY-Weight],
  PW.LY AS [LY-Weight],
  PW.PY AS [PY-Weight]
FROM
  Pivot_Price AS PP INNER JOIN Pivot_Weight AS PW
ON
  PP.month = PW.month AND
  PP.item = PW.item AND
  PP.store = PW.store AND
  PP.manager = PW.manager
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thai's exactly what I need!